# Communication failure in JDBC Database?

Tags: jmeter

[image: Got communication failure in response message]

Got error message as response "message as communication failure" i have added mysql connector in lib folder. can you please suggest me solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your hostname in the [JDBC URL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html) doesn't seem to be correct.

You need to change `phpmyadmin.co` to "what you use as the server name" in the phpmyadmin.co website:

[image]

Also you need to ensure that you're able to reach your server on the given port `3306` using [telnet client application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Telnet_clients) or equivalent

Check out [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article for more information on performing databases load testing using JMeter

Comment: sql12.freesqldatabase.com hostname in server field@Dmitri

Comment: then change `phpmyadmin.co` to `sql12.freesqldatabase.com` in your URL